# "No module named". Python error in gdb

Tags: python, c, gdb, qemu

I'm working on a class project (don't worry, this question is not homework) and recently moved from department machines to my own machine.
The project is to build a simple operating system. To make the task easier, we are provided with the ability to "attach" gdb to QEMU in which our program runs. Running this program without attaching gdb on my computer works fine, however it is when I start trying to use gdb that it does not run.
The main thing to note (I think) is that it runs fine on the department computers (gdb 7.4.1-debian) but not on mine (7.6.1-ubuntu).

The error I am getting pertaining to python is that gdb extensions are written in python but they do not seem to be found. I am also getting syntax error. A run of the program looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/weenix.dbg...done.
```

After which it hangs for a bit, then gives me this error:

```
inittmp.gdb:1: Error in sourced command file:
localhost:1234: Connection timed out.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/mm/memcheck.py", line 5, in <module>
    import weenix
ImportError: No module named 'weenix'
  File "/home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/mm/page.py", line 15
    print "pagesize: {0}".format(weenix.kmem.pagesize())
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/mm/slab.py", line 40
    print "{1:<{0}} {3:>{2}} {5:>{4}} {7:>{6}}".format(
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/proc/proc.py", line 17
    print weenix.proc.str_proc_tree()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/util/debug.py", line 3, in <module>
    import weenix
ImportError: No module named 'weenix'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfonso/course/cs167/weenix/kernel/util/list.py", line 3, in <module>
    import weenix
ImportError: No module named 'weenix'
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc0008f04: file util/debug.c, line 190.
Breakpoint 2 at 0xc0007016: file main/kmain.c, line 298.
Breakpoint 3 at 0xc0006cf3: file main/kmain.c, line 129.
init.gdb:6: Error in sourced command file:
The program is not being run.
```

Of course, the import errors and invalid syntaxes made me initially think about my PYTHONPATH and/or package settings, but that is something that works fine (tested it). The only thing I can think of is that I have some configuration problems that I am overlooking.

If you would like me to, I can post the bash script, .gdb files and the rest, but since this works fine on department computers, I doubt this is the problem.

Python versions: (department: "2.7.3", me: "2.7.5+")

EDIT:
After some searching, I have realized that the newest Linux Mint(petra) uses gdb that interprets python as python3. I am currently looking for a way to configure gdb, but as I have never done it before, I would appreciate if someone could direct me in doing so.

Comment: its complaining about the "weenix" module. the syntax error may be because of that

Comment: Hi praveen, could you elaborate? The module is named correctly and set up correctly (according to my PYTHONPATH testing). The only thing that the syntaxerror makes me think of is that for some reason gdb expects python3. Do you know of a way to check this/change it?

Answer (score 1):

You use Python 3 for this debug mode.

```
$ python3 test33.py
  File "test33.py", line 1
    print "hello".format()
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Make sure you use Python 2 as you say.

Comment: Do you know of a way to explicitly check and change the python version used by gdb? Also, does this imply that pathname resolution (the other error) changed between python versions? It's quite confusing, as I have python 2.7 by default and assumed this is what gdb uses.

Comment: Thanks anyway :) Running ldd $(which gdb) showed that gdb depended on libpython3.3. Apparently newer versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint have gdb interpret python3 by default even though the default version in use is 2.7. The only way I read of fixing this was to remake gdb explicitly stating --with-python. However, this failed for me. Even though I probably did it wrong, I had had enough by that point.

Comment: I suggest you rename the title of that question and write your coment into the question.. I will then delete the answer so more people look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this homework, too. (I guess weenix is too commonly used for OS courses.)

Regarding "import weenix" problem, it's because weenix's python script isn't in gdb's *data directory*. When using gdb with python, this dir will be added to python's PATH automatically. Therefore, just put "weenix/python/weenix" under your *data directory/python*. As for me, it's */usr/shared/gdb/*.

Having fun with weenix!